# Plotly's Scatterpolar: How to change theta's range?

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

I'm using Plotly's scatterpolar chart to visualize several datasets.

Here's a part of my code. Below, I create the scatterpolar instance:

```
go.Scatterpolar(
    r=[dataset_dataframe['word_count'].median(),
       dataset_dataframe['char_count'].median(),
       dataset_dataframe['capitals'].median(),
       dataset_dataframe['num_exclamation_marks'].median(),
       dataset_dataframe['num_punctuation'].median()],

    name=dataset_name,
    theta=['No. of Words', 'No. of Characters', 'No. of Capitals', 'No. of Exclamation Marks', 'No. of Punctuations'],
    fill='toself',
    line=dict(color='brown'),
    subplot=subplot_name),
)
```

And here I put it in a layout:

```
fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(visible=True, )),
    title='Dataset Statistics')
```

I do this for multiple data frames which allows me to easily compare them. The result is neat and looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, it appears that the range of `theta` is calculated automatically using the maximum value of `r` of each scatterpolar instance.

This is not good because, to easily compare the datasets, I need `theta` to be in the same range for all plots.

**Question:** How can I set the range of `theta` to a custom value, e.g., from 1 to 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the `radialaxis=dict(visible=True, )),` you should be able to add `range=[ 1,100 ]`

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me!  Appreciated for it!

Answer (score 7):

Just as an addition because it took me over an hour to figure out: if you are working with subplots, this line might be your friend:

```
fig.update_polars(radialaxis=dict(range=[0, 1]))
```

This will apply the range to all subplots. If you just call `fig.update_layout()` it will only apply the range to the first subplot.

Comment: Quite often you might be adding subplots in a for loop. In which case, just do what konse suggests but don't forget to add the column and row such as fig.update_polars(radialaxis=dict(range=[0, 1]),col=c,row=r)

Comment: The original line by konse worked for me. Didn't have to specify col=c,row=r. You can still create the subplots in  a for loop like you describe but just put the fig.update_polars() at the very end, outside the for loop. It works.

Comment: It solved my problem. tkx.